# How to always open new files in the top window of an already running instance of an application on OS X?

Tags: macos, alfred

I run OS X Mountain Lion and open files in four ways:

- the Finder
- [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) file search
- the `open` command typed directly into the shell
- shell scripts that run `open` and are triggered by applications like Alfred or [Keymando](http://keymando.com)

My primary editor is MacVim.  I observe that sometimes when I open a file, it opens in the current window of MacVim.  In other instances, it will open a new window.  There is a similar phenomenon when running web searches from Alfred.  Sometimes, a new tab will open up in a preexisting Safari window; other times it opens in an entirely new window.  In Safari preferences, I have "open pages in tabs instead of windows" set to "Always".

I can't figure out what the pattern is here.  Can anybody explain how it is that the system decides whether to open in a new or preexisting window, and how to make it always use the preexisting one?

Comment: I don't know about MacVim, but Safari opens a new window if for example you have edited the text on the location bar or some sheet is shown.

Comment: Aha!  That's something.  I don't really get the point of it though-- is there any way to disable it?